# Алгоритм работы поиска товаров по тегам

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Какой самый разумный алгоритм поиска и сортировки товаров по тегам?

У нас есть категории товаров в магазине, к примеру в виде дерева:

```
Техника
--- Мобильные телефоны
--- Ноутбуки
--- ...
--- Смарт-часы
```

Сами категории хранятся в базе данных.

Не самое разумное решение в каждой категории создавать суб-категории:

```
"телефоны - андроид"
"телефоны - андроид - 2 ГБ ОЗУ"
"телефоны - андроид - 3 ГБ ОЗУ"
и так далее...
```

Логичнее под товар создать свои теги. Какой должна быть реализация тегов? Смотрел реализацию в других движках и проектах, многие используют текстовое поле и теги через запятую, а после осуществляют множественный поиск, что не является лучшей идеей, если эти теги необходимо выводить и как то сортировать по ним товары.

В голову приходит только следующая мысль:

1. Таблица с самими тегами, которая включает в себя ID тега, его названием и возможно другие данные (к примеру ID категории для которой применим данный тег).
2. Таблица с товаром, в которой для конкретной задачи необходим ID товара.
3. Таблица, записи которой содержат ID тега и ID товара к которому привязан тег:

   product_id (ID записи в таблице продуктов)
   tag_id (ID тега который привязан к продукту)

Но данный вариант кажется слишком громоздким и в случаи большого числа записей банальный "where" будет работать медленно, особенно, если поиск будет осуществлен по нескольким тегам. Какие в целом существуют оптимальные способы реализации тегов товара и поиска по ним? (число товаров 100к+, у групп товаров может быть до 50 тегов).

Comment: Ваш вариант хороший. Банальный `where tag_id in (1, 2, 3)` будет работать быстро. Что вас смущает?

Comment: Да, в целом работает нормально. Позже хотел удалить свой вопрос, но всё же решил его оставить. Оставил две таблицы, сам продукт и таблицу "тегов" с добавлением ключа `products_tags (product_id, tag_id) USING BTREE;` В таблице тегов идет вставка с ID товара и ID тега, на выходе я получаю по выбранным тегам нужные записи product. Опять же, интересна реализация в других проектах, так как в различных движках магазинов реализация разная и зачастую очень костыльная.